# Instragram Login using Api , But give me erroe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, facebook

i need a help in Instagram login , i am not able to login give me some error i try but not solved

`***Api Service in Angular** *

```
  private apiUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
 private headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  });
  instagramExchangeToken(appId: string, appSecret: string, grant_type: string, redirectUrl: string, code: any): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('client_id', appId);
    formData.append('client_secret', appSecret);
    formData.append('grant_type', grant_type);
    formData.append('redirect_uri', redirectUrl);
    formData.append('code', code);

    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, formData, { headers: this.headers });
  }
bind 
 exchangeCodeForToken() {
    // const payload = {
    const client_id = environment.client_id;
    const client_secret = environment.client_secret;
    const grant_type = environment.grant_type;
    const redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:4200/login';
    const code = this.code;
    // };

    this.facebookAuthService.instagramExchangeToken(client_id, client_secret, grant_type, redirect_uri, code)
      .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          console.log('Access Token Response:', response);

        }
      );
  }
```

**i want to Instagram login when I got code token but when API hit access token gives me erroe **

`HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', ok: false, …} error :  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …} headers :  HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)} message :  "Http failure response for https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token: 0 Unknown Error" name :  "HttpErrorResponse" ok :  false status :  0 statusText :  "Unknown Error" url :  "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token" [[Prototype]] :  HttpResponseBase`